# Refused to frame 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy, adsense

I implemented adsense, but I have the following error message printed in the console when loading a webpage with ads on. Thing is it loads this error message sometimes, not every time I reload the same page.

> Refused to frame 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src
> cm.g.doubleclick.net googleads.g.doubleclick.net [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
> accounts.google.com
> pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/s/cookie_push.html gmsg:
> [https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sadbundle/..."](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sadbundle/...%22)

I have the following CSP policies set on my Node server :

```
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: [
        "'self'",
        'googleapis.com',
      ],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
      frameSrc: [
        "'self'",
        'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/',
        'cm.g.doubleclick.net',
        'googleads.g.doubleclick.net',
        'www.google.com',
        'accounts.google.com',
        'https://adservice.google.com/',
        'https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/',
      ],
    },
  })
);
```

Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: Could you show which settings do you have at the `data-matched-content-ui-type="... ??? ..."` in the script of recommended content Ads block.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? no ad block on my Chrome browser. No data-matched-content-ui-type parameter on my AdSense component definition

Comment: "Refused to frame..." message belongs to [Matched content Ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9189566?hl=en). So you should have piece of code like `<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" ... data-matched-content-ui-type="SomethingHere"></ins>`. I think you have misconfigured `"SomethingHere"` part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Matched content seems to be a type of ad unit to select. I select the default recommended ad type (which is not matched-content). It doesn't have data-matched-content-ui-type as parameter in the ins tag.

Comment: I found a [tread](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/56491863/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0?hl=en) with exactly the same problem, but it's in Russian. You can use Google Chrome's built-in translation feature to read it.

Comment: Judging by the list of sources in the blocking message, it is not your CSP that blocks iframe, but Google's CSP.